# Override of pure virtual function compiles but does not carry out task

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

What is the best way to call the following function from my main function(shown below)?

Everything compiles but the "SetReferrer method"  I reference in a custom class does not work.  I am calling a custom MyResourceHandler class from the below function but I do not think the function is being called form my main function.

How to call this function from my main function?

```
virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> GetResourceHandler(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request) {

    //return NULL;
    return new MyResourceHandler();
```

}

The SetReferrer method,(in CefRequest class),  I am referencing from  method in the custom MyResourceHandler class:

```
virtual void SetReferrer(const CefString& referrer_url,
                           ReferrerPolicy policy) =0;
```

The pure virtual function I override to reference the SetReferrer method from:

```
 bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) {

    CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
    request = cef;
    CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
    request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
    return true;
    //cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);};
};
```

My custom class that is called from the function above:

```
class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
{
public:
MyResourceHandler()
//offset_(0)
{}

  bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) {

    CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
    request = cef;
    CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
    request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
    return true;
    //cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);};
};

   void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                  int64& response_length,
                                  CefString& redirectUrl) ;


   bool ReadResponse(void* data_out,
                            int bytes_to_read,
                            int& bytes_read,
                            CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;

  bool CanGetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   bool CanSetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   void Cancel() ;

   void AddRef()const {} ;

bool Release() const { return true; }

 bool HasOneRef() const { return true; };
};
```

Class that contains the method I am using:

```
#ifndef CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_REQUEST_HANDLER_H_
#define CEF_INCLUDE_CEF_REQUEST_HANDLER_H_
#pragma once

#include "include/cef_auth_callback.h"
#include "include/cef_base.h"
#include "include/cef_browser.h"
#include "include/cef_frame.h"
#include "include/cef_resource_handler.h"
#include "include/cef_response.h"
#include "include/cef_response_filter.h"
#include "include/cef_request.h"
#include "include/cef_ssl_info.h"


///
// Callback interface used for asynchronous continuation of url requests.
///
/*--cef(source=library)--*/
class CefRequestCallback : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  ///
  // Continue the url request. If |allow| is true the request will be continued.
  // Otherwise, the request will be canceled.
  ///
  /*--cef(capi_name=cont)--*/
  virtual void Continue(bool allow) =0;

  ///
  // Cancel the url request.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void Cancel() =0;
};


///
// Implement this interface to handle events related to browser requests. The
// methods of this class will be called on the thread indicated.
///
/*--cef(source=client)--*/
class CefRequestHandler : public virtual CefBase {
 public:
  typedef cef_return_value_t ReturnValue;
  typedef cef_termination_status_t TerminationStatus;
  typedef cef_urlrequest_status_t URLRequestStatus;
  typedef cef_window_open_disposition_t WindowOpenDisposition;

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread before browser navigation. Return true to cancel
  // the navigation or false to allow the navigation to proceed. The |request|
  // object cannot be modified in this callback.
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadingStateChange will be called twice in all cases.
  // If the navigation is allowed CefLoadHandler::OnLoadStart and
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadEnd will be called. If the navigation is canceled
  // CefLoadHandler::OnLoadError will be called with an |errorCode| value of
  // ERR_ABORTED.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnBeforeBrowse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                              CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                              CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              bool is_redirect) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread before OnBeforeBrowse in certain limited cases
  // where navigating a new or different browser might be desirable. This
  // includes user-initiated navigation that might open in a special way (e.g.
  // links clicked via middle-click or ctrl + left-click) and certain types of
  // cross-origin navigation initiated from the renderer process (e.g.
  // navigating the top-level frame to/from a file URL). The |browser| and
  // |frame| values represent the source of the navigation. The
  // |target_disposition| value indicates where the user intended to navigate
  // the browser based on standard Chromium behaviors (e.g. current tab,
  // new tab, etc). The |user_gesture| value will be true if the browser
  // navigated via explicit user gesture (e.g. clicking a link) or false if it
  // navigated automatically (e.g. via the DomContentLoaded event). Return true
  // to cancel the navigation or false to allow the navigation to proceed in the
  // source browser's top-level frame.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnOpenURLFromTab(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                const CefString& target_url,
                                WindowOpenDisposition target_disposition,
                                bool user_gesture) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread before a resource request is loaded. The |request|
  // object may be modified. Return RV_CONTINUE to continue the request
  // immediately. Return RV_CONTINUE_ASYNC and call CefRequestCallback::
  // Continue() at a later time to continue or cancel the request
  // asynchronously. Return RV_CANCEL to cancel the request immediately.
  //
  ///
  /*--cef(default_retval=RV_CONTINUE)--*/
  virtual ReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return RV_CONTINUE;

  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread before a resource is loaded. To allow the resource
  // to load normally return NULL. To specify a handler for the resource return
  // a CefResourceHandler object. The |request| object should not be modified in
  // this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> GetResourceHandler(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request) {

    //return NULL;
    return new MyResourceHandler();
    //new MyResourceHandler();
  }

class MyResourceHandler : public CefResourceHandler
{
public:
MyResourceHandler()
//offset_(0)
{}

  bool ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                              CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) {

    CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
    request = cef;
    CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
    request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
    return true;
    //cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);};
};

   void GetResponseHeaders(CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                  int64& response_length,
                                  CefString& redirectUrl) ;


   bool ReadResponse(void* data_out,
                            int bytes_to_read,
                            int& bytes_read,
                            CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback) ;

  bool CanGetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   bool CanSetCookie(const CefCookie& cookie) { return true; }


   void Cancel() ;

   void AddRef()const {} ;

bool Release() const { return true; }

 bool HasOneRef() const { return true; };

    //bool CefBase::HasOneRef();

    //void CefBase::AddRef() const;

 // bool ProcessRequest (CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
//CefRefPtr<CefCallback> callback){

//CefRefPtr<CefRequest> cef   = CefRequest::Create();
//cef = request;
//CefRequest::ReferrerPolicy origin = REFERRER_POLICY_ALWAYS;
//request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);
//cef->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);

//}

//IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(MyResourceHandler);
//IMPLEMENT_LOCKING(MyResourceHandler);
};

//void AddRef();

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource load is redirected. The |request|
  // parameter will contain the old URL and other request-related information.
  // The |new_url| parameter will contain the new URL and can be changed if
  // desired. The |request| object cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnResourceRedirect(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                  CefString& new_url) {}

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource response is received. To allow the
  // resource to load normally return false. To redirect or retry the resource
  // modify |request| (url, headers or post body) and return true. The
  // |response| object cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnResourceResponse(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread to optionally filter resource response content.
  // |request| and |response| represent the request and response respectively
  // and cannot be modified in this callback.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual CefRefPtr<CefResponseFilter> GetResourceResponseFilter(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
      CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response) {
    return NULL;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when a resource load has completed. |request| and
  // |response| represent the request and response respectively and cannot be
  // modified in this callback. |status| indicates the load completion status.
  // |received_content_length| is the number of response bytes actually read.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnResourceLoadComplete(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request,
                                      CefRefPtr<CefResponse> response,
                                      URLRequestStatus status,
                                      int64 received_content_length) {}

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when the browser needs credentials from the user.
  // |isProxy| indicates whether the host is a proxy server. |host| contains the
  // hostname and |port| contains the port number. |realm| is the realm of the
  // challenge and may be empty. |scheme| is the authentication scheme used,
  // such as "basic" or "digest", and will be empty if the source of the request
  // is an FTP server. Return true to continue the request and call
  // CefAuthCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time when
  // the authentication information is available. Return false to cancel the
  // request immediately.
  ///
  /*--cef(optional_param=realm,optional_param=scheme)--*/
  virtual bool GetAuthCredentials(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
                                  bool isProxy,
                                  const CefString& host,
                                  int port,
                                  const CefString& realm,
                                  const CefString& scheme,
                                  CefRefPtr<CefAuthCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the IO thread when JavaScript requests a specific storage quota
  // size via the webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota function. |origin_url| is the
  // origin of the page making the request. |new_size| is the requested quota
  // size in bytes. Return true to continue the request and call
  // CefRequestCallback::Continue() either in this method or at a later time to
  // grant or deny the request. Return false to cancel the request immediately.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnQuotaRequest(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                              const CefString& origin_url,
                              int64 new_size,
                              CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread to handle requests for URLs with an unknown
  // protocol component. Set |allow_os_execution| to true to attempt execution
  // via the registered OS protocol handler, if any.
  // SECURITY WARNING: YOU SHOULD USE THIS METHOD TO ENFORCE RESTRICTIONS BASED
  // ON SCHEME, HOST OR OTHER URL ANALYSIS BEFORE ALLOWING OS EXECUTION.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnProtocolExecution(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                   const CefString& url,
                                   bool& allow_os_execution) {}

  ///
  // Called on the UI thread to handle requests for URLs with an invalid
  // SSL certificate. Return true and call CefRequestCallback::Continue() either
  // in this method or at a later time to continue or cancel the request. Return
  // false to cancel the request immediately. If
  // CefSettings.ignore_certificate_errors is set all invalid certificates will
  // be accepted without calling this method.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual bool OnCertificateError(
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
      cef_errorcode_t cert_error,
      const CefString& request_url,
      CefRefPtr<CefSSLInfo> ssl_info,
      CefRefPtr<CefRequestCallback> callback) {
    return false;
  }

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when a plugin has crashed.
  // |plugin_path| is the path of the plugin that crashed.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnPluginCrashed(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                               const CefString& plugin_path) {}

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when the render view associated
  // with |browser| is ready to receive/handle IPC messages in the render
  // process.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnRenderViewReady(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser) {}

  ///
  // Called on the browser process UI thread when the render process
  // terminates unexpectedly. |status| indicates how the process
  // terminated.
  ///
  /*--cef()--*/
  virtual void OnRenderProcessTerminated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
                                         TerminationStatus status) {}
};

#endif
```

The main function:

```
#include "cefsimple/simple_app.h"

#include "include/cef_request.h"

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#include "include/base/cef_logging.h"

namespace {

int XErrorHandlerImpl(Display *display, XErrorEvent *event) {
  LOG(WARNING)
        << "X error received: "
        << "type " << event->type << ", "
        << "serial " << event->serial << ", "
        << "error_code " << static_cast<int>(event->error_code) << ", "
        << "request_code " << static_cast<int>(event->request_code) << ", "
        << "minor_code " << static_cast<int>(event->minor_code);
  return 0;
}

int XIOErrorHandlerImpl(Display *display) {
  return 0;
}

}  // namespace


// Entry point function for all processes.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Provide CEF with command-line arguments.
  CefMainArgs main_args(argc, argv);

 //cef_referrer_policy_t ReferrerPolicy;
//cef_referrer_policy_t =  "origin";




  // CEF applications have multiple sub-processes (render, plugin, GPU, etc)
  // that share the same executable. This function checks the command-line and,
  // if this is a sub-process, executes the appropriate logic.
  int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, NULL, NULL);
  if (exit_code >= 0) {
    // The sub-process has completed so return here.
    return exit_code;
  }

  // Install xlib error handlers so that the application won't be terminated
  // on non-fatal errors.
  XSetErrorHandler(XErrorHandlerImpl);
  XSetIOErrorHandler(XIOErrorHandlerImpl);

  // Specify CEF global settings here.
  CefSettings settings;


  // SimpleApp implements application-level callbacks for the browser process.
  // It will create the first browser instance in OnContextInitialized() after
  // CEF has initialized.
  CefRefPtr<SimpleApp> app(new SimpleApp);






  // Initialize CEF for the browser process.
  CefInitialize(main_args, settings, app.get(), NULL);


  // Run the CEF message loop. This will block until CefQuitMessageLoop() is
  // called.
  CefRunMessageLoop();


  // Shut down CEF.
  CefShutdown();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Where is your implementation of `SetReferrer(...)`?

Comment: 3rd code bracket down. it is the 7th line down:  request->SetReferrer("www.google.com",origin);

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. not sure. I didn't include the right header file. still working